# Julia: LoadError: UndefVarError: setrounding not defined

Tags: julia

I am following along the "Julia Language Documentation Release 0.5.0-dev" and running some of their demo commands, this one is throwing an error. (reference page 28)

```
setrounding(BigFloat, RoundDown) do
BigFloat(1) + parse(BigFloat, "0.1")
end
```

throwing error:

> ERROR: UndefVarError: setrounding not defined

but it does not seem like setrounding should be a variable, but a function.

Comment: What version of Julia are you using?

Comment: Yeah just realized, I'm using 0.4.2. Is that a problem?

Comment: For version 0.4, I think the function is [set_rounding](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/numbers/#Base.set_rounding) (with an underscore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working on v0.4, you need to look at the 0.4 docs, rather than the 0.5 docs that you are seeing. At the bottom right of the page, you will see a little black box with a green arrow. Click it, and select the version of the documentation you want.

In this particular case, the name of this function has changed between 0.4 (the latest release) and 0.5 (the current development).

[image: version selector]

Answer (score 2):

In Julia 0.4, there were two different functions, `set_rounding` to change the rounding mode outright, and `with_rounding` that you would use in the example you wrote, which changes the rounding mode only temporarily during the given function (in your case, the code in the `do...end` block).

In Julia 0.5, these were merged into the single `setrounding` function, that performs both of these tasks, and, in line with the tendency for functions in `Base`, no longer has an underscore (`_`).

The discussion about this renaming can be found in the original Pull Request: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13232

You can also use the new 0.5 syntax even in 0.4, by doing 
`using Compat` first; this is the Julia backwards-compatibility module, which in this case will define the `setrounding` function with the correct behaviour. (You need a version of `Compat` at least 0.7.11; if you have a previous version, just do a `Pkg.update()`.)

e.g.

```
julia> using Compat

julia> setrounding(BigFloat, RoundDown)   # 0.5 syntax
3

julia> get_rounding(BigFloat)   # 0.4 syntax -- not advisable to mix these!
RoundingMode{:Down}()
```